# Vue Composables best practices

Tags: phpstorm, vuejs3, webstorm, vue-composition-api, composable

I need your help when writting [good composables](https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/coding-better-composables-1-of-5/) in Vue 3. Looking a the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#conventions-and-best-practices) I can see that composables should be a **function**. That's ok.

However I don't feel confortable with this because I lose IDE help and autocompletion.

For example, if I have a `useUtils()` composable like this:

```js
// composables/useUtils.js

export default function useUtils() {
  const isAdmin = () => true;
  const isUser = () => false;

  return {
    isAdmin,
    isUser,
}
```

Then, when writting code in PhpStorm/WebStorn, the IDE does not autocomplete (either auto import) the utilities functions described inside my `useUtils()` composable :(

For example, if I start to write:

```js
const canCreate = isAdm //<-- Here I would like IDE to autocomplete and autoimport!
```

That doesn't work because IDE is not able to know what should autocomplete.

**Workaround**

If I define the composable as a bounch of exported functions however, it works correctly:

```js
// composables/useUtils.js

export const isAdmin = () => true;
export const isUser = () => false;
```

Now, the IDE knows all available functions and does a good work autocompleting and autoimporting everything.

In addition, when using this approach, I also get's the ability to know what things of my composable **are being used and what not**, that's very cool. It doesn't happen when deffining a function. But I feel bad because Vue docs says that composables should be a function T_T

So, here is my question:

What do you do guys? Are there a way to configure the IDE for a better integration when writting composables? Is very bad to use a bunch of funtions?

Give me any tip please,

Thanks!

Comment: you can start entering `useUtils`, the IDE will then complete and auto-import it;

Answer (score 1):

I usually do:

```js
const useMyComposable = () => {
  const myData = ref("something");

  const myFunction = () => {
    // ...
  }

  return {
    myData,
    myFunction
  }
}

export { useMyComposable };
export default useMyComposable;
```

So now in a random component I get the autocompletion working.

Comment: Thx for your comment! However, I tested it and it did not work in PhpStorm/WebStorm :( 
Using your example, in a random component, if I start to write 'myD' I expect to get `myData()` autocompleted and `import { myData } from '../composables/useMyComposable'` auto imported, but It did not happen

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but to import data from a composable you first need to import the composable itself.
`import { useMyComposable } from "../composables/useMyComposable";` and then you can `const { myData } = useMyComposable()`